# How to parse a string object into a json object

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsp, bufferedreader

im receiving in a JSP page some information in a buffer, i manage to build a array with that. My question is, how can i parse this string object to a json object and than get the values, for finnaly print it on a notepad.txt line per line.

**JSP Page to get the buffered data**

```
    <%@ page import="java.io.BufferedReader"%>
<%
try {

        String body = null;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

        try {

            // aqui está o ponto: tem que abrir uma stream e ler os bytes, não vem pronto.
            bufferedReader = request.getReader();



            char[] charBuffer = new char[128];
            int bytesRead = -1;

            // precisa ler todos os caracters do buffer de entrada do request.

            while ((bytesRead = bufferedReader.read(charBuffer)) > 0) {
                stringBuilder.append(charBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
            }

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw ex;
        } finally {
            if (bufferedReader != null) {
                try {
                    bufferedReader.close();
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }
        }


        // pronto aqui está o conteúdo da chamada
        body = stringBuilder.toString();

        System.out.println("Body:["+body+"]");


} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {

}

%>
```

Body:

```
[
  [
    {
      "summary": {
        "externalInputs": [],
        "accessPointId": 2,
        "authorizedCount": 0,
        "closedTime": null,
        "detectedCount": 0,
        "endTime": 1422493644041,
        "enteredCount": 0,
        "eventId": 12760,
        "identifiedCount": 0,
        "openedTime": null,
        "siteId": 1,
        "startTime": 1422493583912,
        "systemFailure": null,
        "unlockedTime": null,
        "assistanceRequested": false,
        "blacklistedPersonDetected": false,
        "doorOpenedManually": false,
        "doorRemainedOpen": false,
        "hasEnded": true,
        "tailgatingDetected": false,
        "wasDoorOpened": false
      },
      "entityDetailList": []
    }
  ]
]
```

**Trying to simplify my question, i need to parse this array to print in a notepad.txt, line per line.**

Answer (score 0):

You can use the org.json library to parse JSON objects, its very lightweight and pretty simple to use. 
 [org.json](http://www.json.org/java/)
You can import the library and use it create a JSON object or JSON Array in ur case , something like this. :

```
body ; // Your JSON String 
JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(body);
System.out.println(jArray.get(0).get("summary").toString());
```

Hope this helps you out.

Comment: I importe the following library - <%@ page import="org.json.simple.JSONArray"%> but now im getting this erro on new JSONArray(body); -> The constructor JSONArray(String) is undefined